# Static Variables and Methods in Java

Tags: java, static

I am confused about when to use Static variables/methods and exactly what they do. I know Static means that the variable or method becomes a part of the class and not an instance, but when do we use this? Also, if a variable is static, does that mean it is immutable like a final variable? Basically what is the use of Static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will usually use static when your variables are general and are not supposed to be part of each instance separately, take as an example the number pi, if you create a Math class, you will set pi as a static final variable, and also the methods will be declared as static, because you don't want to create a class instance everytime you want to use the power function. If your function doesn't use the properties of the class it will probably be static.
Another use I found useful, when you create a class within another, you should declare the inner class as static, otherwise you will need an instance to create instance of the inner class